# Join() in CI replacing key id

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I have two tables, one for users and one for products.

Users

id name
1  john
2  bill

Products
id userId product
1  1      test
2  2      test

I created a search function in the model so I can call usermodel->search($productId). In this function, the Products table is queried with a user table join like so:

```
return $this->db->join(UserModel::TABLE_NAME, ProductModel::TABLE_NAME . '.userId = ' . UserModel::TABLE_NAME . '.id')->get($this->_tableName);
```

The issue I am having is that the Product id is being replaced by the userId. Can someone point in the right direction for why this might be happening? I am a noob to joins in sql, thought I understood them, but this is baffling me a bit.

Comment: What does `$this->db->last_query()` return immediately after you do that join?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (`products`)
JOIN `users` ON `products`.`userId` = `users`.`id`

Comment: Try changing the SELECT * to SELECT products.id,users.id as u_id,(list of fields you want), probably since both your PK's are named the same when you try to retrieve them it is only returning you the id of the table users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try this:

```
    $this->db->select('Users.id as user_id,Products.id as product_id'); // you can write other fields using comma 
    $this->db->from("Users");        
    $this->db->join("Products",'Products.userId = Users.id','LEFT');
    $query = $this->db->get();     
    echo $this->db->last_query();   
    return $query->result_array();
```

Can you please post the query using this code.

Comment: Finally got back around to this. Just had to add in the right fields, thanks.